# Dynamically insert data into an APEX page item when a page item is entered a value

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have a form in APEX that is used to add data into a table. Most of the items in the form are free form texts but there few items that are needed to auto filled when you enter a value in on of the page item.

For example.

There is form with Page Items. ID, Name, TitleLevel, Title_prefix, Salalry,

There is a table XYZ with Title_prefix and salary info which

ID    Title_prefix   Salaray

1   Junior         80000

2   Mid-Level      95000

3   Senior         115000

So you enter ID= 1, Name = ABCD, Titlelevel = 6 is entered and Title_prefix and salary should be populated based on the value that is entered in titlelevel. In this case it will be

Title_Prefix = (SELECT Title_Prefix FROM XYZ WHERE ID = (Case WHEN :P1_TitleLevel > 5 THEN 3 CASE WHEN :P1_TitleLevel = 5 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END))

Same thing for Salary as well.

Immediately after entering Titlelevel page item to 6 the Title_prefix and Salary should get refreshed and populate this items. Then the user will submit the form so that the information can be entered into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Dynamic Action on titlelevel (Key Release if Text Field, onChange if dropdown etc.)

Add a PL/SQL Action to the dynamic_action, using Items to Submit to pass fields in and Items to Return for the fields you modify.

Dynamic Action:
[image]

OR
[image]

Action:
[image]

Comment: This solution worked fine. I used Change Event and build multiple dynamic action.